# Meteor Google Calendar Push notification "Unauthorized WebHook callback channel"

Tags: meteor, google-calendar-api, google-authentication

I want to use google calendar notification.
I have deployed my Meteor application to 
`https://google-push-notification.meteor.com`
I have verified the url in google web master.
Added the same domain to Domain Verification of Google Console.
I have created Meteor rest api of https://google-push-notification.meteor.com/api/articles for get and post method both.
 Below is the postman collection of apis. `https://www.getpostman.com/collections/106be7c94d35fcbdb0f8`

```
Post https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/abc@gmail.com/events/watch

Authorization: Bearer ya29.YwJdqjlSv8Tkl5MEJgiVXQPGxE24ZfITuf8gt0C8DO_VHDvB_1mRAgpAx64R6Wpw8I6fiw

Content-Type: application/json

{


"id": "ya29.XwI-RJ54rS3dbRHgak8V_iTuV7uAWJoZfRFnUE76uCIIUbw4eILPsdEME56Jm5_EfDtWWWs", 

"type": "web_hook",

"address": "https://google-push-notification.meteor.com/api/items"


}

I am getting the following response

{
"error": {
    "errors": [
        {
            "domain": "global",
            "reason": "push.webhookUrlUnauthorized",
            "message": "Unauthorized WebHook callback channel: https://google-push-notification.meteor.com/api/articles"
        }
    ],
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Unauthorized WebHook callback channel: https://google-push-notification.meteor.com/api/articles"
}

}
```

Why am I getting `push.webhookUrlUnauthorized` response even when I have verified my site in google and added the same domain in google console.
Can anyone please help us to solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

According to the google [forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-calendar-api/ZHKwm2xWuNE), make sure you have validate the following items below:

1. Please make sure to follow the steps to correctly verify that the domain indeed belongs to you here: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35179
2. It must be a https endpoint and the same endpoint must also be present in the developer console as per instructions here: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push#registering

Hope this resolve your issue. Cheers!

Comment: Yes. I have followed  the steps correctly and verified many times. This https://google-push-notification.meteor.com/api/articles is my web hook url . It contains https and https://google-push-notification.meteor.com is verified in google webmasters and added the same in domain list,

Comment: Did you solve your issue ? I have the same error on notifications for google API and my conf should be fine.. (I can access to other webservices like list my calendar and modify event and my domain is registered and https)